# usort of session array not outputting as expected

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, session, usort

I have a grid of img squares that can be dragged into any order using the sortable library. Each img is a visual representation of a result from a mySQL db query that selects any image that shares an *'imageparent'* identifier. The order they're presented in the grid is taken from the *'imageorder'* column in the database and starts at 0 and works in sequence up to the nth number of images returned.

The purpose of dragging the img grid is to be able to change the *'imageorder'* index. On completion of the drag, the sortable library `POSTS` an *'imageorder'* var by ajax to `service.php` and is received correctly. So rather than the original *0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7* order of the original, it sends a string like *2,1,0,3,4,5,7,6*. Not too hard to grasp. After I switch the order the `orderList` var sent to `service.php` is always correct, but the array I end up sending to the db and setting as my session var becomes a little garbled in order after the second or third drag and I'm not quite sure why.

### Code Examples and Comments

---

**$_SESSION['selectedCsImages'] Array structure:**

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [imagename] => "Title"
        [imageorder] => 0
        [imageid] => 43
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [imagename] => "Title"
        [imageorder] => 1
        [imageid] => 21
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [imagename] => "Title"
        [imageorder] => 2
        [imageid] => 3
    )
etc...
```

**Services.php extract:**

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
// Turn the orderList posted into an array
$removeChars = array('"','[',']');
$orderList = str_replace($removeChars, "", $_POST['order']); // POST received fine.
$listArray = explode(",",$orderList);
// Retrieve the session array
$sorting = $_SESSION['selectedCsImages'];

/* My logic is that I compare the $sorting array to $listArray and reorder $sorting by 'imageorder' to match $listarray */
usort($sorting, function($a, $b) use ($listArray) {
    return array_search($a['imageorder'], $listArray) - array_search($b['imageorder'], $listArray);
});
/* I now have a $sorting array that (sometimes, hence the problem) matches the order that the images had just been dragged into by the user. Typically, as I mentioned above, it's correct after the first drag, but not always after the second or third where it creates a new order that I can't see a pattern or logic in. */

/* Had there not been errors with the usort function, I (would) have a $sorting array in the order I want but with imageorder values referring to pre-sorting. I iterate through the array and set each key to 0, 1, 2, etc. so that I have an array in the correct order and with each imageorder correctly stating its place.*/

$i = 0;
foreach ($sorting as $key => $value) {
    $sorting[$key]['imageorder'] = $i;
    $i++;
}

/* The information is attempted to be sent to the db and, on success I update the session var */
// Database code (runs succesfully and updates the db as per the image orders found in the $sorting array)
$_SESSION['selectedCsImages'] = $sorting;
```

### Debugging:

---

From debugging, it appears that something happens with the usort function when I call this page from ajax for the second or third time. Everything after this follows through fine and processes the correct or incorrect order as per expectations. The `orderList` var posted by *sortable* is correct each time. I'd provide a sample of the `$sorted` var after usort each time but it's as simple to describe it as the above array example in an order I didn't specify after dragging and I can't see a pattern in the seemingly random order it outputs.

From researching, I had thought that it was an issue with session vars being retained until the page is refreshed but it appears that the ajax call to services.php should refresh the `$_SESSION['selectedCsImages']` var. I had also read that, perhaps, I was unknowingly using referenced array values and - as I source from a session var to a new array and, ultimately, save back to this session var from this array - I may have created some messy referencing feedback. However, I tried using `$sorted = (array)clone(object)$_SESSION['selectedCsImages'];` before attempting usort and the results didn't change.

PHP error logs are showing nothing.

### Updates:

---

Per the suggestion of @Ayaou, I've checked the output of `$listArray` and am getting some unexpected results. I'd wrongly assumed that as the posted `$orderList` was correct, that the exploded array would not be a culprit.

Here's the output of `print_r($listArray)` after completing the following order swaps of 16 img elements: 1st with 2nd, 2nd last with last,6th with 7th:

```
1st and 2nd:
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
    [10] => 10
    [11] => 11
    [12] => 12
    [13] => 13
    [14] => 14
    [15] => 15
)

last and 2nd last:
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
    [10] => 10
    [11] => 11
    [12] => 12
    [13] => 13
    [14] => 15
    [15] => 14
)

6th with 7th:
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
    [10] => 10
    [11] => 11
    [12] => 12
    [13] => 13
    [14] => 15
    [15] => 14
)
```

I was progressing with the idea that `$listArray` would show a sequential 0,1,2,3,etc. each time with only the two swapped items showing order changes. As it's not, I'll look back again at $orderList and check if my sortable library is updating the orders it's obtaining correctly from the updated session var. Older order swaps are being retained somewhere along the chain where they shouldn't.

Comment: Can you post the content of `$listArray`

Comment: Suggest you do some isolated tests on the sorting part (a script containing only that, plus static variations of $listArray contents - check if the result matches what you expect for different cases) – not sure if that is really able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, I was attempting that just before I wrote the question and still working through it now. @Ayaou, you may be onto something, cheers. I assumed that `$listArray` would be a culprit as it was exploding a string I'd checked was correct. However, it seems to be produced unexpected output. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is on your `sortable` form (on the front end), so instead of sending the `imageorder` on your `'order'` post data, send the `imageid` index.

Then change your sort callback like this

```
//Use imageid index instead of imageorder
usort($sorting, function($a, $b) use ($listArray) {
        return array_search($a['imageid'], $listArray) - array_search($b['imageid'], $listArray);
    });
```

Comment: This was exactly it, thanks Ayaou. It was a conclusion I might have wasted too much time coming to as I'd gotten complacent about the sortable side being the issue due to the whole front and back-end being from code I'd previously written that worked perfectly. All I changed was the database procedure and something went haywire along the way. It turns out I'd been using the image order as an id for each image somehow. But your hunch was correct and was what solved it.